# const char* acts weird

Tags: c++, char

so i recently got some really weird errors in my C++ Project! I'm recieving a 32 Chars long string from a TCP client and store it in a const char*, like this:

```
serverData.Salt = "";
NetDll_recv(XNCALLER_SYSAPP, Sock, serverData.Salt, 32, 0);
if (!(serverData.Salt != NULL))
    return false;
printf("Salt: %s\n", serverData.Salt);
serverData.Salt = "";
```

after storing it in serverData.Salt(as you can see) i print it to my Debug-Console, but now the weird thing comes in... All const char* or char* i declare like

```
const char* example = "";
```

have the value of this serverData.Salt, i never do anything with serverData.Salt besides the lines of codes i posted, that's why i'm asking for help, because this messed up my whole Project...

Thanks in Advance :)

By the way, this is the struct:

```
struct ServerData
{
    const char* Salt;
};
ServerData serverData;
```

EDIT:

This is a Example:
So i do all the code i posted above and later in my Project i initialize the variable score:

```
const char *Score = "";
```

It's "" because i dont need it at that time, and it will be placed on the screen, as a hudelement that will show the users score when being ingame, now lets take "12345" as what the server returned and wrote into serverData.Salt, so now if im at the main menu of my game the score should be "" but it is "12345" even though i never did anything to it in the code at this point of time... so it kind of got the value of serverData.Salt

Comment: What? This _'messed up'_ your whole project? In what way? Are you getting errors? Which ones? You seem to have forgotten to include the actual question

Comment: Make a [mcve], otherwise you will only get downvotes and possibly guesses.

Comment: @ForceBru, the error is that all `const char*`'s i declare have the same value as the serverData.Salt, i recieve fe "12345" and after that i declare `const char* example = ""` and when i print this example it shows "12345", i'm developing a game and some hudelems like score or others now have the value of "12345" and this text is over my whole gameinterface when playing...

Comment: Post any code that refers to any pointers initialised with `""` and any code that makes any modifications to said pointers or - worse - their referents. If you don't want to post it all, the reduce it to an MCVE that exhibits the problem in the smallest possible space. Otherwise, guessing about possible UB is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: There is no "if you don't want to post it all": there is only _don't_ post it all. A MCVE is not optional. You should have one already anyway if you've spent any time debugging this yourself, because creating one is part of debugging.

Comment: I can't find docs of `Netdll_recv` with simple googling, but presumably this is a C API requiring a buffer, and you're passing it a pointer to an empty string literal. If so then that's **Just Wrong™**. Voting to close as lacking reproducible example due to lack of info about that function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: There is more than enough information to answer this question. The cause is very clear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You make two assumptions. (1) that the presented code isn't the real code (lacking a crucial cast). (2) that the function invoked is a normal C API function requiring a buffer. That's *likely*, but it's just a guess. It can be wrong.

Comment: See, you call this a "C++ project", but it smells like C to me. I see no C++ features here whatsoever. If you were really using C++, you'd be using `std::string` instead of `char *`s everywhere, would have allocated a `string` (or even a good ol' `vector`) to act as the accepting buffer, would've `reserve()`d it to have enough memory for what it's about to receive, and would've not had any problems. Also, you'd be using `std::cout` and saving yourself further UB from likely accidental mismatches of specifiers and arguments there, too.

Comment: Seems like you didn't allocate any buffer able to receive data in `salt` field.

Comment: "32 Chars ... and store it in a const char*" - no. You cannot store 32 chars in a pointer. You store them in an **array**. Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times: "an array is not a pointer".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: We _should_ have an MCVE, but it seems dishonest to claim that we cannot say with a normal degree of confidence what the answer to the problem is. But the correct answer is somewhere in between the two of us I think :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't store characters "in" a `const char*`; you can only have a `const char*` that points to some buffer. In this instance, you are asking `NetDll_recv` to store its data in a buffer that comes from a string literal (`""`). Bad and wrong!

You know already that this is bad and wrong because, although you didn't tell us, you had to cast `serverData.Salt` from `const char*` to just `char*` to make your code compile.

After you've mutated the memory taken by a string literal, all bets are off. You are seeing *undefined behaviour* in action, probably a permanent corruption of the memory space inside your process that stores string literal data. That's why the value keeps popping up elsewhere. To add insult to injury, you've gone *way* beyond the bounds of the original string, which had zero characters in it (not counting null termination).

You need to stop treating `const char*` as string objects. Either use `std::string` like you should, or at least allocate a buffer that you actually own, in which to store the new data, and make your `char*` point to that.